# How to extract File Object from Django Form FileField

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-file-upload

I have created a ModelForm with fields, `title`, `file` and `content`. Here `file` is a FileField(). But I can't call the `save()` method of this form due to some reasons. So I have to maually created one Model Object and assign cleaned values to that object. Everything worked excpt that FileField. The file is not saving. How can I fix this? Is it the correct method to extract FileField?

Form

```
class TestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Test
        fields = ('title','file', 'content',)
```

Views.py

```
 form = TestForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
 if form.is_valid():
     content = form.cleaned_data['content']
     file = form.cleaned_data['file']
     title = form.cleaned_data['title']
     fax = Fax()
     fax.title = title
     fax.file = file
     fax.content = content
     fax.save()
```

Here the file is not saving. How can I fix this?
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: instead of form.cleaned_data['file'], use request.FILES['file'] - see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/?from=olddocs#file-uploads

Comment: Why can't you call the save method on the form? The ought to be the right way to do it.

Comment: @super9 its because I have create more than one object with that. There is a loop in the code, which I have omitted to describe it easily

Answer (score 6):

Have u used `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form
Seems like the code is fine.

Answer (score 2):

Please using this type of validation. This may work

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ModelFormWithFileField(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        # file is saved
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/url/')``
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use

```
request.FILES['file']
```

for getting the file object